# WPF UserControl with TextBox, use TextChanged event C#

Tags: wpf, user-controls, textbox, textchanged

I have a customer usercontrol that is a labeled `TextBox` (`Border` wrapped about a `Label` and a `TextBox` with the `TextBox` overlapping the label). I am finding few (working) examples on how to get the `TextChanged` function to work when called from my UserControl.

Just the textbox snippet:

```
<TextBox 
FontSize="{Binding Path=DefaultFontSize}"
Style="{StaticResource WatermarkTextBox}"
Padding="{Binding Path=TextPadding}"
Tag="{Binding Path=TextValue}"
/>
```

I have tried using `RoutedEventHandler` like I did with my button's Click event, but it didn't work. How do I get it so when let's say I use on the window it is required:

```
<MyControl:LabeledTextBox
    TextBoxChange="Some_Event"
    TextValue="{Binding SomethingOrOther}"
 />
```

that it will fire off correctly and do the needed function

Comment: Are you saying you want to define an event for your UserControl and hook to it?  Or that you want your binding to work properly?  Or something else>

Answer (score 3):

This question's really unclear.  Do you want your user control to support a `TextChanged` event that gets raised when the text in the `TextBox` changes?  If so, you need to implement it in the code-behind.

First, declare the event:

```
public event TextChangedEventHandler TextChanged;
```

Then, add an event handler to the `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" ... />
```

and in the code-behind:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{
   TextChangedEventHandler h = TextChanged;
   if (h != null)
   {
      h(this, args);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MVVM (Or if your `TextValue` binding is binding to something you can get to and edit) you can put the logic you want executed in the setter.

So, lets say you are binding to a property `MyTextBoxValue`.  Set the binding mode to two way in the XAML, and in the setter put the logic or call to another method.

If you want the code to fire every time you type, set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in XAML, if you want the code to fire only when text entry is "done" set `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`.